# Days between two dates doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I need to compute the days between two dates (format YYYYMMDD)

I used two test dates, 2020-01-20 and 2020-02-20

```
$enddate = "20200220";
$startdate = "20200120";
$s = new DateTime($enddate);
$e = new DateTime($startdate);
$diff = $s->diff($e);
echo "days: ".$diff->d;
```

the result is 0 instead of being a month worth of days

> days: 0

I understand that dates as strings might be ambiguous, so I also tried to specify the format, by doing:

```
$enddate = "20200220";
$startdate = "20200120";
$s = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $startdate);
$e = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $enddate);
$diff = $s->diff($e);
echo "days: ".$diff->d;
```

Still got 0

> days: 0

Comment: `echo "days: ".$diff->days;`

Comment: @JohnConde it works! but why I get 0 when I access the "d" field ?

Comment: Because they're both on the 20th. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: `var_dump($diff)` would have immediately exposed what you were doing wrong, btw.

Comment: *"I used two test dates, 2020-01-20 and 2020-02-20"* - Funny, your declarations contain no hyphens.

Comment: No issue with your date, its ok to use date without dashes, Check my answer @GianlucaGhettini

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
<?php

// strtotime converts any string date format to unix time

$date1 = "2020-01-20";
$date2 = "2020-02-20";

$seconds_in_a_day = 86400;


$diff = (strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1))/$seconds_in_a_day;

echo $diff; // output 31
```

Comment: `strtotime()` is not made for this and can give incorrect results. `Datetime()` is the right tool for this job and the majority of the work related to working with dates.

Comment: This also doesn't explain why they see the results they are getting

Comment: This looks like an answer from 15 years ago. Why would you suggest `strtotime()`?